# Qt ODBC SQL_SERVER

Tags: c++, qt, odbc

I would like to use the SQL_ATTR_TRACE=SQL_OPT_TRACE_ON option of QSqlDatbase object.

> QSqlDatabase db_;
>
> db_.setConnectOptions("SQL_ATTR_TRACE=SQL_OPT_TRACE_ON");

I'm wondering where the resulting trace file is located ?

Is there a way to define the path ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it exists a SQL_ATTR_TRACEFILE attribute

```
  db_.setConnectOptions("SQL_ATTR_TRACEFILE =c:\\odbc.log");
```